# Find the minimum value of two digits using returns code hs python

Tags: python

> Write a function called `minVal` that returns the minimum of the two numbers values passed in as parameters. Note: Be sure to include comments for all functions that you use or create. For example, if you made a call like `x = minVal(10, 14)` `x` should have the value `10`. For your program, you need to define the function and call it and print out the result like this:
>
> ```
> x = minVal(10, 14) 
> print("The min is " + str(x))
> ```

here is what i have.

```
def minVal(x,y):

    if x<y:

        minVal==x

    else: y=minVal

    return minVal
    
   
x=minVal(2,4)

print("The min is" + str(x) )
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `y=minVal` should be `minVal = y`

Comment: Write a function called minVal that returns the minimum of the two numbers values passed in as parameters.

Note: Be sure to include comments for all functions that you use or create.

For example, if you made a call like

x = minVal(10, 14)
x should have the value 10.

For your program, you need to define the function and call it and print out the result like this:

x = minVal(10, 14)
print("The min is " + str(x))

Comment: That's not the question. I meant what question do you have about the code you posted?

Comment: You are using the == operator wrong, you can’t assign variables using that, that’s to test for equivalence.

Comment: @anarchy There's no test in the `else:` statement. That's an assignment, but it's backwards.

Comment: OHHHH THANK YOU @Barmar

Comment: To summarize `minVal = x` instead of minVal == x and `minVal = y` instead of `y=minVal`

Comment: But really there's no need for the variable at all, and having the variable name and the function name be the same thing could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
def minVal(x, y):
    return x if x < y else y

x = minVal(2, 4)

print("The min is " + str(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

> With Two Different Options

```
def minVal(x, y):
    if x>y:
        return x
    elif x==y:
        return None
    else:
        return y
```

> With a List With Two Items

```
def minVal(l1):
    if l1[0]>l1[1]:
        return l1[0]
    elif l1[0]==l1[1]:
        return None
    else:
        return l1[1]
```

The second is a poor idea. There is no guarantee l1 will have two items, and if it has more, then the function isn't guaranteed to return the minimum value in the entire function. Also, returning None is odd. If they are equal, then surely returning either one will return the minimum value.

Comment: The second is a poor idea. There is no guarantee `l1` will have two items, and if it has more, then the function isn't guaranteed to return the minimum value in the entire function. Also, returning `None` is odd. If they are equal, then surely returning either one will return the minimum value.

Answer (score -2):

```
def minVal(x,y):
    
    return min(x, y)
    
x=minVal(2,4)

print("The min is " + str(x))
```

**Output:**

```
The min is 2
```

Comment: The built-in `min` doesn't need to take a list. You could just write `min(x, y)`. But in that case we might as well implement `minVal` as: `minVal = min`